# CSS problem with box shadow and floating box

Tags: html, css, shadow

I have two divs floating next to each other, with class name div1 and div2. I use box-shadow to get a nice shadow on both divs. The problem is that I want the shadow from div1 to lay over div2, to get the feeling that div2 is sticking out from behind div1. Now I get the shadow from div2 to be over div1 instead. Hope you understand my problem. Is it possible to fix this?

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

This is the css:

```
.div1 {
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
}

.div2 {
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
}
```

Comment: don't use CSS to do that. Use images and nested divs instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give both of the a background color - elements are transparent by default, thus causing their shadows to "stick out" behind each other. To lay them over each other, simply use the [`z-index`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index) CSS property.

```
.div1 {
    z-index: 99;
}

.div2 {
    z-index: 100;
}

div {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 5px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
}
```

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/wspDP/4/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. We want div1 to appear in front and z-index doesn't work for shadows.

Comment: @Steve Excuse me? The solution obviously worked for the OP, or else he wouldn't have marked it as accepted. If it doesn't work for *you*, then obviously you have a different question here.

Comment: Then someone should fix the question, as this is pretty clear to me   "The problem is that I want the shadow from div1 to lay over div2, to get the feeling that div2 is sticking out from behind div1."   I've tried your solution in FF and Chrome with no luck.

Comment: @Steve What I understand from the question is that he wants *one* of the shadow to appear *on top of* the other element. That's what my solution does, and that's what he accepted. If it does not answer *your* question, then I'm sorry, you've found the wrong question. But you have no right to decide on behalf of the OP on what *he* wants.

Comment: He clearly says the problem is that div2 is showing above div1 and asks how to get div1 above div2.  Your solution does exactly what his does already. This has nothing to do with my question, it's simply that this StackOverflow question and answer is misleading to anyone who finds it in the future.

Comment: @Steve, I think the onus is on you now to better express what you mean. Paste a link to an image or something.

Comment: @Steve This is about as much as I can do to explain what is happening here: http://jsfiddle.net/cgycF/2/embedded/result%2Ccss/ You can see the result for yourself, but like I said, the OP *has* accepted this answer as been useful in solving his problem. I do not understand why you're trying to dispute this fact *on behalf* of the author.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Steve was right here - while the z-index was partly the solution it's not solved the issue of which div goes on top.  For anyone who comes to this question looking for that answer, the solution above will work as long as you remember that anything that uses a z-index must have a position: relative for it to work - thereby enabling you to specify which div lies on top.

Comment: It is clear what the OP meant, synthesizing: he wants to arbitrarily make an element to show above another whilst keeping the same relative positioning flow (any doubt about that), z-index solves it. Any given example code can be inaccurate or flawed (yet better be not) and still outline the problem, hence I see here that the answer responds what the OP explicitly intended to ask, z-index worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.div1 {
    z-index:80;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #aaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
}

.div2 {
    z-index:-10;
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    float: left;
    left:560px;
    top:30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #A0A0A0;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">asdf </div>
  <div class="div2">asd asdf</div> 
</div>
```

z-index higher mean that div will be on top, so you can adjust as per the need, but to give exact feeling , you may need to play with colors , dark shadow vs light shadow.